# How to share or open the pdf file using whatsapp in iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf, whatsapp

I am developing an `iOS` app which generates a `PDF`. I want to share and open that pdf using my app. 
I tried to use the : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052 sample app. But, except mail and print, its not giving any other app to open it up with even though `whatsapp` is installed.

So how exactly to use `DocInteractionController` to share files using `whatsapp`?
I followed : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1 and https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013.

Thanks

Comment: So do you want to open a PDF using whatsapp or simply open a PDF in one of your Views ?

Comment: Use `UIWebView` if you want to just open in your application, and if you want to `Open With` some other apps, follow this link http://www.g8production.com/post/54417573525/open-with-in-ios-uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Comment: I want to open it using whatsapp and share the file using whatsapp

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think whatsapp support PDF file to share it only support, video, images, locations, contacts etc.

Comment: Ok then. How can i share videos or images?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot @iphonic.

Whatsapp supports only images, videos not pdf or text file.

So we can use http://www.g8production.com/post/54417573525/open-with-in-ios-uidocumentinteractioncontroller for those types and leave the rest!